# Israel's list of designated terrorist organizations?

Tags: israel, terrorism

I have found [this Excel spreadsheet](http://www.mod.gov.il/Defence-and-Security/Fighting_terrorism/Documents/%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%aa%d7%a7%20%d7%a9%d7%9c%20terror%20-%20%207-7-2015.xls) written by [Israel's Ministry Of Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Defense_%28Israel%29).

Is it a list of organizations considered by the [MOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Defense_(Israel)) as terrorist? Or does it only list organizations **helping** terrorist organizations? Or **suspected** of doing so?

I guess the columns tells something about what the organization is accused of doing? In that case, what value(s) in what column(s) mean that the row is directly classified as a terrorist organization?

Comment: Please link to the page which contains the spreadsheet as well (if possible).  There's nothing in the spreadsheet itself to indicate anything about who created it.

Comment: @Bobson: I have found that URL used as a reference here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations

Comment: Trivially answerable - document is hosted on official website. Column E has the reason for the addition to this list (Tip: Google Translate)

Comment: As a native Hebrew speaker, I still can't answer your question because it's not clear enough

Comment: @haim770: Thanks for your feedback! Many nations maintain their own "official list of terrorist organizations", for instance here is [Australia's list](http://www.nationalsecurity.gov.au/Listedterroristorganisations/Pages/default.aspx). Everything clear so far? Now, does the Excel spreadsheet above contain that information for Israel? If yes, are all rows of the Excel sheet terrorist organizations, or just some of them? If just some of them, how to distinguish? (ex: "ABC" in column X means officially listed as terrorist). I hope my question is clearer now?

Comment: The link to your Excel file is broken. Try the 2 links in the bottom of http://www.mod.gov.il/Defence-and-Security/Fighting_terrorism/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: @haim770: Thanks for the tip! Would you mind telling me what is the difference between these two files?

Answer (score 1):

The document contains several types of organizations, as they are categorized in column E.

Some of the classifications, for example, are:

- Unauthorized gathering according to the defense ordinances
- Declaration of a terrorist organization, according to the anti-terror act
- Declaration of a terrorist organization, according to the anti terror funding act

As you can see, there are different declarations according to different laws and regulations, and for different purposes.

For instance, people that work in organization 'A' might never have hurt a single person, but they assisted in funding organization 'B' that is doing all within its power to do so.

And there might be some people in organization 'C' that do neither, but may be promoting terrorist violence, so there is another regulation that is relevant to them.

And there is much more, but essentially it all comes down to the classification.